# R compare group to full sample

Tags: r, testing, statistics, t-test

Sample data

```
df <- data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "group"=c(0,0,1,1,1), "score"=c(10,14,15,13,12))
```

My goal is to compare the scores for group = 1 to the complete sample.

I figured how to do the t test:

```
t.test(df$score ~ df$group)
```

But is this for group = 1 versus group = 0?

Comment: yes that is group 1 vs group 0

Answer (score 0):

You can subset your df to only keep one group and then in the original data make all the groups the same. Combine the two `data.frame`s so now you have the complete sample as one group and group one still separate. Then do the t-test.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 "group"=c(0,0,1,1,1), 
                 "score"=c(10,14,15,13,12))

#make group = 2 so this is the 'complete sample'
df2 <- mutate(df, group = 2)
#keep only group 1
df1 <- filter(df, group == 1)
#put together so that you have group 1 vs complete sample
df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)

#do t-test
t.test(df3$score,df3$group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could just

```
t.test(df$score[df$group==1], df$score)
```